# Javascript Login alphabets only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code and i can't connect my html to javascript
I want to log in username and password with alphabets only

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<title>Login Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js">
</head>

<body>
<div id="dumdiv">
<form name="frm" method="post" action="login.php" id="f1" onkeyup="AllowAlphabet()">
    <table>
      <tr>
 <td class="f1_label">User Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="username" value="" />
            </td>
                </tr>
      <tr>
```

Password :

```
this is the javascript file

<script type="text/javascript">
function AllowAlphabet(){
           if (!frm.alphabet.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) && frm.alphabet.value !="")
           {
                frm.alphabet.value="";
                frm.alphabet.focus(); 
                alert("Please Enter only alphabets in text");
           }
}      
</script>
```

Comment: you must use the funtion on either form submit or on keyup of our input field.

Comment: Cannot put `onkeyup` event on form element

Answer (score 0):

you should put onkeyup on the input field not on the form

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" onkeyup="AllowAlphabet()" />
```

Comment: where should i place it? can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Add function `AllowAlphabet` into your input element `onkeyup` event

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" onkeyup="AllowAlphabet(this)" />
```

And change your function in `javascript` with this

```
function AllowAlphabet(ele){
   if (!$(ele).val().match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) && $(ele).val() !="")
   {
        $(ele).val("");
        alert("Please Enter only alphabets in text");
        $(ele).focus(); 
   }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T6U9G/1/

**UPDATE:**

Finally your code will look like

In your html:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="login.php" id="f1">
    <table>
      <tr>
 <td class="f1_label">User Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="username" value="" onkeyup="AllowAlphabet(this)" />
            </td>
                </tr>
      <tr>
 <td class="f1_label">Password :</td><td><input type="password" name="password" value="" onkeyup="AllowAlphabet(this)" />
            </td>
                </tr>
```

And in your javascript:

```
function AllowAlphabet(ele){
   if (!$(ele).val().match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) && $(ele).val() !="")
   {
        $(ele).val("");
        alert("Please Enter only alphabets in text");
        $(ele).focus(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: when i preview it on chrome it is just blank

Comment: @user3230905 you added the function into the input keyup event?

Answer (score 0):

If you use browser support HTML5 can use as

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Alphabet only">
```

else you can use as Peace answer